# InitializeServiceContext in Initializer.cs has started throwing "Unauthorized" in my test app

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Using the c# devkit against qbo.  When i left yesterday everything was working, however today  attempting to initialze the servicecontext in my test application I started getting the "Intuit.Ipp.Exception.InvalidTokenException: Unauthorized" error.

```
ServiceContext context = Initializer.InitializeServiceContext(oauthValidator, realmId, string.Empty, string.Empty, dataSourcetype);
```

and the error is here in the InitializeServiceContext:
    context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, realmId, intuitServiceType);

I registered my test company yesterday (i.e. I now have a paid quickbooks online account)  am i not allowed to continue testing against a real account?  Or have i made a bigger error somewhere.

Thanks

Edit:

When trying to log into my test app on the Intuit Developer Playground I'm getting the following error:

```
Oops! An error has occurred.

Please close this window and try again.

Error Code: internal_error
Message: Error Authorizing Request Token: <redacted-token>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your OAuth tokens are no longer valid.  Initializing the ServiceContext object for QBO retrieves the base URL for the realm, which requires authorization and is throwing the unauthorized error as a result.

Comment: Problem solved.

I had not sufficiently read the documentation.

I was still using the OauthAccessTokenStorage.xml from the sample code, which was not expiring the oAuth tokens.

thanks for your help